# Redirect http page to https

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Just a quick one - would anyone know the correct htaccess code to redirect a register.php page from http to https? When the site isn't on the register.php page it should redirect back to http://sitename.com/register.php.

Many thanks.

Comment: Use your imagination while reading: http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/force-ssl-htaccess.html. You would need two redirects, as also stated in your question.

Comment: look on http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html

Comment: Sorry - should've mentioned that my existing code looks like: #RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^register\.php$ https://www.site.com/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] but not working

Comment: This will definitely help, http://tinyurl.com/38jqw33

Comment: You have to redirect to `https://site.com/folder%{REQUEST_URI}`. All you're doing is redirecting from a non-https link to the same non-https link

Comment: Thanks Marc. Would it be too much to ask how I would go about resolving it? I'm not a htaccess expert, in fact, I'm not an expert in anything programming-related really.

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about .htaccess, but I think this page may be of use:  http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html